# How do shutdown android 12+ device programmatically

Tags: android

I have an app with system privileges (rooted android and the app is installed as system app) and I wish to integrate an automatic shutdown functionaly when battery level is low. I tried all the methods I can find such as the `"su -c 'reboot -p'"` and also the intent `android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN`. The shell command doesn't trigger the shutdown basically it doesn't do anything when I try with the broadcast as such:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN");
        intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_CONFIRM", false);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

I am getting `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN`.

Is there a way to shudown the device programmatically on newer android devices?

Comment: By "system privileges" do you mean a rooted device or an app that runs as system app? Because `su` is only present on rooted devices. So a system app can not expect it to be present.

Comment: Rooted and installed as system app. I edited the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by using the following command:

```
su 0 reboot -p
```

instead of `su -c reboot -p` (this doesn't work on my device)

Apparently su -c runs a single command while su 0 opens an interactive shell. Not sure why -c wasn't working though.

Here is my code that works:

```
   String command = "su 0 reboot -p";
   Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
   int exec = proc.waitFor();
```